# Web to Lead form not displaying special characters and symbols

Tags: html

Instead of `"Hope it's going good"`, it is `"Hope it&rsquo;s going good"`. Is this a website encoding issue or a setting in Salesforce?

Comment: looks the same? which special character you talking about?

Comment: got it, edited your question to clear.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15776365/html-best-practices-should-i-use-rsquo-or-the-special-keyboard-shortcut

Comment: @PranayJaiswal Thanks for the edit. Can you explain the link you shared?